# PhP Group array result or dump array result

Tags: php, arrays

**I have the following php array and would like to group the results:**

```
array:3 [▼
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "trashed" => 1
    "passed" => 0
    "failed" => 2
    "unknown" => 0
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "trashed" => 0
    "passed" => 1
    "failed" => 0
    "unknown" => 3
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "trashed" => 0
    "passed" => 0
    "failed" => 0
    "unknown" => 0
  ]
]
```

**How can i group them for example:** without going through loops? I would love to learn about an array_sort or merge function that does this :D

```
$trashed = [1, 0, 0];
$passed = [0, 1, 0];
```

I can rename the $key to anything if numbers is better approach or may assist in answering the question.

There will not be any null $keys or $values in this.

**I'm currently doing it like this, but it seems ugly:**

```
$trashed = [];
    
foreach($months as $month){
    array_push($trashed, $month['trashed']);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with loops?

Comment: @Cid nothing really, I'm just interested in learning a new approach if available/possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `array_column()` for this, as is demonstrated by the example below. Keep in mind though, that `array_column()` does internal looping of its own. It's good to see you're eager to learn new/other solutions, but generally performance and simplicity are some of the basic goals of any application.

If you want to avoid using a loop, then I suggest building the array differently in the first place. Why not use the `trashed` etc. keys as keys to their own respective arrays?

Here's one possible approach using `array_column()`. See comments for explanation and output.

```
<?php

// Your input array.
$a = [
    1 => [
            'trashed' => 1,
            'passed' => 0,
            'failed' => 2,
            'unknown' => 0
    ],
    2 => [
            'trashed' => 0,
            'passed' => 1,
            'failed' => 0,
            'unknown' => 3
    ],
    3 => [
            'trashed' => 0,
            'passed' => 0,
            'failed' => 0,
            'unknown' => 0
    ],
];

// Fetch all values for each key and return them as an array.
$trashed = array_column($a, 'trashed');
$passed = array_column($a, 'passed');
$failed = array_column($a, 'failed');
$unknown = array_column($a, 'unknown');

var_dump($trashed);
var_dump($passed);
var_dump($failed);
var_dump($unknown);
/*
Output:
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(0)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(0)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
}
*/
```